# Dijkstra's Algorithm with Negative Weights Query

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

In this scenario, the aim is to find a path with the smallest total weight. There are 5 sections with each section having different nodes. The nodes are only connected to nodes in adjacent sections and a path must consist of only a single node from each section.

For example, let:

- section 1 has nodes [1, 2, 3].
- section 2 has nodes [4, 5].
- section 3 has nodes [6].
- section 4 has nodes [7, 8, 9, 10, 11].
- section 5 has nodes [12, 13, 14].

A valid path through the sections is [1, 4, 6, 7 , 12] and also [1, 5, 6, 11, 14] etc...

All nodes have negative weights but negative cycles are impossible (due to the one node per section policy). Therefore, does the process of adding a constant to each node resolve the issue of negative weights? If it can fix the issue, are there any papers which show this? I know there are other algorithms to resolve negative weights but I'm interestted in Dijkstra's algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, adding a constant fixes the problem in this case, but in an acyclic graph there are faster and simpler ways, like DFS.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I second that. Dijkstra is just an incredibly poor choice for this problem. You don't have to think about Bellman-Ford. You just relax edges from left to right in O(n+m) and you're done. I don't understand how DFS could help, though.

Comment: Relax edges from left to right? Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: "Edge relaxation" refers to the process of checking whether a node's total distance (from the source) can be reduced by adding an edge's length to the distance of the start.
Since you have weights for nodes (not vertices), the easiest way is as follows:
Assign all nodes in section one their weight as distance. Then proceed with section two. For every node, calculate the minimum distance of a connected node in section one and add the node's weight. That is the minimum path cost to each section two node. Repeat the same for the following levels. In level 5, pick the minimum.

Answer (score 3):

No, you **can't do** this. Let's have a look at the *counter example*. Suppose we have a graph with `A`, `B`, `C` nodes and egdes:

```
A - B  -2 (negative)
A - C   6
B - C   7
```

we are looking for the shortest path from `A` to `C`. In the original graph we have

```
A - B - C  => -2 + 7 = 5 (the shortest path, 5 < 6)
A - C      => 6
```

The best choice is `A - B - C`. Now, let's get rid of *negative* edges by adding `2`. We'll have now

```
A - B  0 
A - C  8
B - C  9

A - B - C  => 0 + 9 = 9
A - C      => 8         (the shortest path, 8 < 9)
```

Please note, that now the shortest path is `A - C`. Alas! While adding constant value to each edge we *ruin* the *problem itself*; and it doesn't matter now which algorithm we use.

**Edit:** Counter example with *all* edges (*arc* to prevent negative loops) being negative:

```
A -> B -6
B -> C -1
A -> C -5
```

Before adding `6` we have

```
A -> B -> C = -6 - 1 = -7 (the shortest path)
A -> C      = -5
```

After adding `6` we get

```
A -> B  0
B -> C  5
A -> C  1

A -> B -> C = 0 + 5 = 5 
A -> C      = 1 (the shortest path)
```

Comment: Makes sense. However, all weights are strictly negative. Does it work in this case?

Comment: @hi hi: You can't add constant value to edges; all negative weights is not the exception (please, see my edit)

Comment: Good answer. Is the Bellman–Ford algorithm the best algorithm to use in this case then?

Comment: @hi hi: Bellman-Ford is quite easy to implement and it provides the right answer. As for the *best* you should specify the criterium; for instance, in case of *huge* graph A* search can be preferrable.

Comment: there are 12 sections - each having around 30 nodes. Isn't A* just Dijkstra with a heuristic meaning it wouldn't work in this case? I need the optimal path.

Comment: @hi hi: well, `12` and `30` are tiny numbers (were they be `12_000_000` and `30_000_000` we should think on A*); Bellman-Ford seems to be quite OK

Comment: Sorry to ask again but how can A* work but not Dijkstra in this case?

Comment: @hi hi: Dijkstra algorithm has `O(n**2 + m)` time complexity, which means that for large graph with `n ~ 1e6` we have about *trillion* operations (several days) to perform. Dijkstra algorithm computes shortest pathes from A to *all* the other nodes (when we want just one path from `A` to `C`) and these unwanted solutions is the problem.

Comment: I see, so Dijkstra is very slow in this case. Are you saying that Dijkstra would work in this case or not? The example given in your answers both have A -> B and A -> B -> C paths. However, these don't exist in my case as nodes can only be connected to nodes in adjacent sections.

Comment: @hi hi: If and only if *all* valid (not necessary shortest) pathes (in your case) contanes *same* number of edges you can add constant number to *each* edge and run Dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: Is this really a counterexample? In the problem statement, the nodes form sections, so every solution has the same number of vertices.

Comment: @Bastian J: if and only if *all* valid paths have *same* number of *edges* we can add some constant number to each edge weight. If we have a constant number of *vertice*, in general case we *can't*. However, if we have for each path constant number of vertice and *no loops* it guarantees the *same* number of *edges*  condition; that's why we can add constant number to each edge weight

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Sure, but isn't the question specificly setting this scenario? Given the problem statement and the examples, there are n sections, and nodes in section k have arcs to nodes in section k+1 only. If you look for a path "through the sections" I am assuming a path starting in section 1, ending in section n, having n nodes.